# Render MVC view from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two separate projects one in MVC and another in ASP.NET. 
I have a function in MVC which render a view and convert it into a stream which is working absolutely fine.

I am using this function from ASP.NET using dll to render MVC view from ASP.NET.
Problem is razorViewEngine.FindView always return null.

Any kind of help to render MVC view from ASP.NET will save my time as well as save me from rework.

```
public static Stream RenderView<T>(string controllerName, string viewName, T model, Dictionary<string, object> viewData = null)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var contextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(context);
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(contextBase, routeData, new EmptyController());
        var razorViewEngine = new RazorViewEngine();
        var razorViewResult = razorViewEngine.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, "", false);
        var writer = new StringWriter();
        var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary<T>(model);

        if (viewData != null)
        {
            foreach (var d in viewData)
                vdd.Add(d.Key, d.Value);
        }

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, razorViewResult.View, vdd, new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
        razorViewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writer.ToString());
        return new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    }
    class EmptyController : ControllerBase
    {
        protected override void ExecuteCore() { }
    }
```

Comment: controllerName, viewName, model, viewData :)

Comment: Try passing null in 3rd parameter.

Comment: model has all the data if I pass null what will render?

Comment: 3rd para is not model, it's master view

Comment: passed null but no progress

Comment: I don't know it there is a fix for mvc4-5, but this bug is known in asp.net core mvc https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6676 But the actual problem in asp.net mvc, it seems that views are not precompiled, so in your second project when you import dll as reference, it can't find the View Folder, because it's not compiled.